# How do I read from a non-text file in c (linux)?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to send files(one chunk at a time) through a UDP socket. It works fine for .txt files but when I try to read from .jpg/.rar it reads only a few bytes(less than I "ask" for) even though the files are >2mb .

I tried using both open/pread(i also tried using lseek and read) and fopen(in binary mode)/fread/fseek and I get the same result(i.e. for a 2mb .jpg file i get this output "read 10 from offset 0").
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

this is the code responsible for reading a chunk from a file:

```
void * work(void * p){
...
int psize=100;
int file;
//FILE *file;

//open the file
file=open(wArg.req.fileName, O_RDONLY);
//file=fopen(wArg.req.fileName, "rb");

//read the file chunk from the offset
buff=(void *) malloc(psize);
n=pread(file, buff, psize, wArg.req.offset);
//fseek(file,wArg.req.offset, SEEK_SET);
//fread(buff, 1, psize, file);
if(n<0){
    perror("read");
    exit(1);
}

printf("read %d from offset %d\n", (int)strlen(buff),wArg.req.offset);

n=sendto(wArg.sock, buff, psize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&caddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
printf("sent %d\n", (int)strlen(buff));


close(file); 
//fclose(file);
...
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check that `malloc` returned a valid value. It is possible that `buff` could not be allocated due to insufficient memory.

Comment: What is pread()? Your life could become easier if you used the gcc flags `-Wall -Werror` always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary file can contain `NULL`-bytes, `strlen` will stop counting after finding such a `NULL`-byte. Use the return-value of `pread` to find out the size of the `buff`er.

All `str`* functions expect C-strings, which must *end* with a `NULL`-byte and cannot have them 'in the middle'.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take `strlen (buff)` because `buff` is binary data.  When you do `pread`, the return value that you captured in `n` contains the number of bytes read.  You should use that instead of `psize` in `sendto`.

Answer (score 0):

pread() reads up to count bytes from file descriptor file at offset offset (from the start of the file) into the buffer starting at buf. The file offset is not changed.
Since it is a binary file so strlen can't work here...
So use pread and initialize psize to return value of pread().